# How to find derivative of this intergral?

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes, partial-derivative, stochastic-calculus

Let $\alpha(t)\in\{0,1\}: 0\leq t\leq 1$ be a two state continuous Markov chain
with the generator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain) 
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
    -\alpha & \alpha\\
\beta &-\beta\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assume that $\alpha(t)=i \in\{0,1\}$.  Let $$f(t)=\int_t^1\mathbb{I}_{\{\alpha(u)=1\}}(u) du $$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function.

My questions:

1)  How to find $\frac{df}{dt}$

2) Can we find the density function of $f(t)$ ?

Comment: You need an initial condition for $\alpha(t)$.

Comment: Dear A.S: it is assumed that $\alpha(t)=i\in\{0,1\}$